# Trying to replace data based on attributes from two other columns

Tags: replace, find, powerquery

I need to change the inventory category for a couple of account numbers and only for a couple of companies.  The inventory category for these accounts are mapped based on the account number but need to be changed specifically just for two companies.  I've tried to filter by the company number and then find/replace, which worked fine, but then I can't unfilter to bring back the rest of the companies.  I can't change the category for just those account numbers because it is only different for just those two companies.

Answer (score 0):

Lisa, Here's perhaps a simpler approach than where your current way is taking you.

If I begin with this table:

[image]

Then I add a column (Add Column -> Custom Column) with the following:

[image]

The formula uses an if statement to determine whether each row has a specific *Account* (Acct. 4) AND *Company* (Co. 8). If so, then 99 is returned as a new category value for that row of the new column. If not, then the original *Inventory Category* is returned as a value for that row of the new column. (Obviously, you would edit this formula accordingly, to support your account, company, and new inventory category values.)

Here's the result:

[image]

Then I could delete the original *Inventory Category* column and rename the remaining *New Inventory Category* column to *Inventory Category*.